# Xamarin form: Navigation bar hiding part of the listview on android

Tags: android, xamarin, navigation

[image]

That was the initial position of the list. The first row was hidden behind the navigation bar. I am using Shell to setup the application. Not sure which part causing the listview hidden by the navigation bar

Below is the xaml of this page

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Actions" IconImageSource='settings' Clicked="Action_Clicked" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="true" RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
        <d:ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>First Item</x:String>
                <x:String>Second Item</x:String>
                <x:String>Third Item</x:String>
                <x:String>Fourth Item</x:String>
                <x:String>Fifth Item</x:String>
                <x:String>Sixth Item</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </d:ListView.ItemsSource>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" d:Text="{Binding .}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" FontSize="16" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Description}" d:Text="Item description" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}" FontSize="13" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Try removing the StackLayout and see if that works for you!

Comment: Provide the code in Android Project ->Resource->values->style.xml .

Comment: Also make sure you are on the latest version of Xamarin.Forms

Comment: I've never used shell, and I can't say I have used a toolbaritem, but can you put it in the StackLayout? See if that helps, if not, i am wondering if it has to do with the VerticalOptions being FillAndExpand, perhaps it needs to be StartAndExpand so that this way it won't try to occupy the whole screen?

Comment: I wondering if it is a shell or a emulator issue ( could be insufficient code for the example). I pretty much made my ItemSource be  what yours is, granted I did get rid of the d: prefix since it won't render the itemsource then. My toolbar is on the top. I made my selected event just push a new ContentPage and it works fine, no issues

Comment: Actually there was a previous page before this but have no problem.

Comment: You could share a sample so that I can test it on my side.